# Import value from other contract

Tags: contract-development

I am trying to pass configuration values from one contract to another, so I can change them and avoid transaction fees.

I have two contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./two.sol";

contract One{

    string name;

    constructor() public{

    }

    Two two;

    function getNameFromOtherContract() public returns(string) {
        name = two.getName();
        return name;
    }
}
```

And second:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Two{

    constructor() public{
    }

    function getName() external pure returns (string name) {
        name = "Amel";
    }
}
```

When I triger getNameFromOtherContract I get:

> transact to One.getNameFromOtherContract errored: VM error: revert.
>   revert    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.

What would be the correct syntax and solution for this approach?

Comment: Is unclear how you are planning to avoid transaction fees using this approach. Two is not deployed, or is it?

Answer (score 2):

1) You're `one` contract is not setting the variable `two` to the deployed `two` contract's address. This is why you're getting a `revert` error.

Rev A) fixed code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./Two.sol";

contract One{

    string name;
    Two two;

    constructor() public{
        two = new Two();
    }

    function getNameFromOtherContract() public returns(string) {
        name = two.getName();
        return name;
    }
}
```

Rev B (actually setting the address of contract `two` via the constructor of contract `one`. Note: this requires `two` to be deployed before `one`)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./Two.sol";

contract One{

    string name;
    Two two;

    constructor(address _two) public{
        require(_two != address(0));
        two = Two(_two);
    }

    function getNameFromOtherContract() public returns(string) {
        name = two.getName();
        return name;
    }
}
```

2) I'm not sure how you're going to accomplish this part: `change them and avoid transaction fees.` Please explain further and I'll be happy to assist.

Comment: I will use call functions which do not change state so there is no transaction happening which means there is no mining.

Comment: `call functions which do not change state `  This means you can read variables but not change them. 

Changing variables require a state change - which requires a tx.

Comment: Correct, that’s what i want to achieve